Path of docker-compose.yml as environment variable
I have to set a environment variable to the absolute path of the docker-compose.yml file. I tried ${PWD} (see below). However, as expected, PWD is the path from where the docker compose command is executed and not the path of the docker-compose.yml file.
How can I do this?
In case this is not possible, is there a way to configure docker compose that it always changes the PWD to the location of the docker-compose.yml file?
services:
    environment:
      TEST_ENV: ${PWD}/data


That environment variable will be used in the container, which won't have access to the host filesystem; using the host path of the Compose file won't be that meaningful to the container code.  Can you use a fixed container path here instead?

This environment variable is used by the container to create volumes (bind) on new container it spawns.

you can either use environment file and set the path manually, use a script to dynamically set the path, use Docker Compose Override Files or lastly use Docker Compose variable substitution with .env . apart from these i dont think there are any option , plase check the above and try to meet your requirements.
